# Expected LBRACE at line xxx col 2

Tags: css

I did a change in the style.css of a wordpress-Theme. when I want to save it, the debugger shows the error:

> Expected LBRACE at line xxx col 2.

First question: what is meant with col 2?

Second question: what is wrong with the code and how do I have to change it?

```
    *html #header {
    position: absolute;
    left: expression( ( 0   ( ignoreMe2 = document.documentElement.scrollLeft ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : document.body.scrollLeft ) )   'px' );
    top: expression( ( 0   ( ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop ) )   'px' );
}
```

the `px` is in red color, does it mean this is wrong? What must I write instead?

Comment: In what file is this "css" exactly? That is not pure css.

Comment: It is in the original style.css of the theme

Comment: That expression-method is an old (now deprecated) IE-only feature. So remove it and implement that behaviour some other way.

Comment: Hmmm. I am not a real coder, only grafik designer. I know little css and html. What do you think is the behavior wanted, and how to implement it whereto?